# Correct pattern to select files using glob

Tags: python, file, split, operating-system, glob

I have a collection of files with name `austin1.tif`, `austin2.tif` ... `austin36.tif`.
For 8 different cities. I am trying to separate `austin1.tif` ... `austin5.tif` from `austin6.tif` ... `austin36.tif`. I came up with many solutions, but want to filter these files only with glob function.

```
root_dir = os.path.join(DIR, "train")
pattern = "[a-zA-Z]*[0-5].tif"
images = glob.glob(os.path.join(root_dir, "images", pattern))

print(sorted(images[:10]))
```

Above code snippet gives me, files with name `austin1.tif` as well as `austin11.tif`. I know this is because of incorrect pattern. What can be the correct pattern that can be directly used in glob.?

Comment: What you seem to be looking for is a regular expression but unfortunately, glob doesn't support full RE - it uses Unix style pattern matching. You could consider using a simple glob pattern of '*.tif' then filter the results based on a RE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the range of files `(1 to 5)`, you just need to move back the wildcard `*` before `[a-zA-Z]` :

```
pattern = "*[a-zA-Z][0-5].tif" # or [1-5]
```

As an output of `images`, you should get something like below :

```
['./train\\images\\another_city1.tif',
 './train\\images\\another_city2.tif',
 './train\\images\\another_city3.tif',
 './train\\images\\another_city4.tif',
 './train\\images\\another_city5.tif',
 './train\\images\\austin1.tif',
 './train\\images\\austin2.tif',
 './train\\images\\austin3.tif',
 './train\\images\\austin4.tif',
 './train\\images\\austin5.tif']
```

Used config :

```
train
┣━━ images
   ┣━━ another_city1.tif
   ...
   ┣━━ another_city40.tif
   ┣━━ austin1.tif
   ...
   ┗━━ austin40.tif
```

Answer (score 0):

`glob` doesn't support [Kleene star `*`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene_star), i.e., multiple repetitions of the previous match. `.*` in [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) equals to `*` in `glob`. You may try

```
pattern = "austin[0-5].tif"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find filenames that start with `austin` and end in `.tif` then you can use

```
austin[0-5].tif
```

This matches 'austin' then a character 0-5 then .tif, so no space for extra characters.

But if you wanted anything that ends in 0-5 you can use

```
*[^0-9][0-5].tif
```

This matches anything, then a character that is not 0-9, then a character that is 0-5, then .tif

You can see the last one in [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tools/glob?comments=true&glob=%2A%5B%5E0-9%5D%5B0-5%5D.tif&matches=false&tests=austin1.tif&tests=austin2.tif&tests=austin3.tif&tests=austin4.tif&tests=austin5.tif&tests=austin6.tif&tests=austin7.tif&tests=austin8.tif&tests=austin9.tif&tests=austin10.tif&tests=austin11.tif&tests=austin12.tif&tests=austin13.tif&tests=austin14.tif&tests=austin15.tif&tests=austin16.tif&tests=austin17.tif&tests=austin18.tif&tests=austin19.tif&tests=austin20.tif&tests=austin21.tif&tests=austin22.tif&tests=austin23.tif&tests=austin24.tif&tests=austin25.tif&tests=austin26.tif&tests=austin27.tif&tests=austin28.tif&tests=austin29.tif&tests=austin30.tif&tests=austin31.tif&tests=austin32.tif&tests=austin33.tif&tests=austin34.tif&tests=austin35.tif&tests=austin36.tif) example.